# Apt Package conflicts with Pip Install

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

There is the `sl` command in Ubuntu that enabled `ls` typos to cause a steam locomotive to run across your screen:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/displays-animations-when-accidentally-you-type-sl-instead-of-ls.html

I have run `apt-get install sl`, but `sl` gets me the SoftLayer Command-line Client v3.3.1, which was installed via pip's `pip install SoftLayer`.  How do I get the ubuntu `sl` program to override the pip install?

---

## Answer

(posted as part of question since question is on hold)

Apt installs sl in `/usr/games/sl`.  Meanwhile, the python SoftLayer library installs sl in `/usr/local/bin/sl`, which has path precedence.  The solution is to create the alias `alias sl='/usr/games/sl'`

Comment: which version of Ubuntu you see this? It correctly installs on my ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: @BlueMoon I'm seeing it on 10.04, 12.04, and 15.04

Comment: The `sl` package in Ubuntu is still that silly tool. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sl

Comment: Do you have non-official repositories enabled?

Comment: Do you mean `apt-get install sl` gets you that tool or that running `sl` runs that client instead of the silly `sl`? What does `type -a sl` output?

Comment: i instaled it just now on ubuntu 14.04 using `apt-get install sl`

Comment: @EtanReisner I've included the contents of my apt sources.  What else do you need?

Comment: What exactly does `apt-get install sl` say at this point? (Presumably that it is already installed.) What does `type -a sl` say?